# What is the best set up for beating The Crucible on Apocalyptic?

Tags: darksiders-2

Ok, so I have recently started over and decided to go through the game on Apocalyptic. I went to The Crucible to get my first possessed weapon and noticed it is rather difficult to get past the first 5 waves. I have beaten The Crucible before on an easier difficulty, I used the Harbinger side of the tech when I did this. I am now trying to find a good build for Apocalyptic. And ideas on what I should use and what my recommended level should be?